# practically how to estimate the exact distance between transmitter and receiver in wireless network

Tags: design, wireless, transmitter, receiver, mobile

I want to know the estimation of exact distance between transmitter and receiver in wireless networks. Can the distance be calculated? What would I have to do to find the exact distance?

Comment: What exactly is "exact" ?

Comment: Nothing in your post has said why this wouldn't be an acceptable solution: Get a tape measure and put one end on the base station and the other end on the mobile unit. Now read the distance off the tape measure.

Comment: estimation of exact distance .... make up my mind....

Comment: Triangulate - two receivers a known distance apart , directional aerials to get angles to transmitter and a bit of basic maths.

Comment: If you know the transmitter strength, and you know the receiver sensitivity you can calculate the maximum range. (both directions if it's something like a cell phone). I am sure you do not need any help to Google that.  Derate that by some acceptable factor that includes a cost analysis and you can calculate how many and how far apart transmitters need to be.

Answer (score 2):

The only observables in a wireless network are

- the time of arrival of a message
- the contents of the message

You can use the former to measure the time-of-flight of the message over the air in order to estimate the distance, but that means that you need to have an accurate idea of what time the message was transmitted. You can get this from the contents of the message, assuming that the transmitter and receiver have adequately synchronized clocks. This is the basis of GPS, for example.

The transmitter can also report its own position in some mutually agreed-upon system of coordinates. Then the receiver can directly calculate the distance between its own position and the transmitter position. Again, you can use GPS to provide the necessary data to both units.

Another observable is the received radio signal strength of the message, but this is a function of so many other things in addition to distance — antenna gain and orientation at both ends, multipath and RF absorption, transmitter power level calibration — that it effectively useless as a distance measurement.

---

Just thought of another observable: Direction of arrival.

If the receiver's antenna is directional enough, it can measure the direction (angle) of the transmitter relative to its own orientation. Measurements from at least two different transmitters (if the receiver knows its own absolute orientation) or three transmitters (if it doesn't) would allow it to calculate its position, which would then allow it to calculate the distance to any or all of the transmitters.

Again, this would be easily confounded by multipath.

Comment: Not sure the travel time part works either. In a digital world where you are sharing the channel with who knows how many other users, the time to send and receive can vary by a large margin.

Comment: @Trevor: That's just an implementation detail. I'm just talking about *possible* observables. If a particular implementation makes something unobservable, then of course it can't be used.

Comment: Yup I realize that, just thought I'd add to your already great answer :)

Comment: Signal strength can be used in some situations. I've managed to get reasonable 3d position (<10 cm RMS error at 20 m range) from RSSI alone. But that system only worked in open fields and had to factor in antenna gain patterns and orientations, base station antenna heights and even the moisture content of the ground. It also took a lot of CPU number crunching (about 20 minutes 6-7 years ago) to get an answer. In a real world situation it becomes a nightmare unless you cheat and map out signal levels around the area.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the path loss characteristics (described by the path loss model). As mentioned in the earlier answer, stated by @MadHatter, you would have:

Received Power = Transmit Power / FSPL

In the dB or logarithmic scale, this would be equaivalent to:

Received Power(dB) = Transmit Power(dB) - 10*log(FSPL)

You can solve the above equations to solve for 'd' given the other parameters.

Now in the case that your path loss is not given by the free space model, then you would have to rewrite the above equations accordingly. In other words,

Received Power(dB) = Transmit Power(dB) - 10*log(Loss)

where Loss depends on the value 'd'.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the frequency and available transmitters, you could attempt to do trilateration based on signal power, otherwise if it is something like a line of sight single TX single RX, you could use Path Loss equations, they are fairly simple and can be accurate for sub GHz frequencies.

Google "free space path loss", there are many basic formulas, here is one from Wikipedia: 
[image]

Comment: Curious as to why this received a down-vote? What is technically wrong with this answer?

Answer (score 0):

In digital systems you can use three transmitter [trilateration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateration).

If you are detecting the exact moment WHEN a packet signal is received at each tower from a particular device, you can calculate the differences between each and calculate a position.

Accuracy depends on how well you can measure that and how granular your tower clocks are.

Comment: Nitpick - Triangulation is when you measure angles to calculate your location. If you are using time of flight then you are basing the calculations on distances, that's trilateration.

Comment: @Andrew, thanks for that clarification... I learned a new word today :)